# Configure JPA to map all enums to String?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

Currently I have to add `@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)` to all fields that use enums, and very often I forget to do it, and then the default kicks in `(EnumType.ORDINAL)`.

Is it possible to configure JPA to map all enums to String? (To make the default EnumType.STRING ?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately not.

But think twice when using enums. I wrote an article about the issues:

https://martinelli.ch/should-you-use-enums-with-jpa/

Comment: You can always try and lobby your persistence provider to consider a custom toggle for such a global change in behavior, but be prepared to argue your case and provide clear reasons why such a change in standard behavior is absolutely necessary.

Comment: You provided a link which is no longer existing.

Comment: @Arny Sorry about that. The link is updated